# Acces ODBC passthru query fails with error 3146 giving different error description texts

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc

I create a passthru query SELECTINg rows of a Postgres v.11 database table.
Running currentDb.execute generates ODBC error 3146 and "invalid argument" mentioned in DBEngine.errors.
Opening same query in the database explorer generates ODBC error 3146 and a message box with "permission denied ..." which actually reflects the source of error.

My questions is how can I programmatically get hold of latter more informative error message ?

Comment: Since this an ODBC/Access issue it would be nice to know what the ODBC driver is as well as the Access version.

Comment: When using DAO, you have very little control over errors and text sent along with the query. Instead, execute the query through ADO, which has more extensive support for errors and events.

Comment: Thanks @ErikA, does your comment imply that ADO is used by MS Access internally when opening the passthru query via the Navigation Pane as opposed to DAO when opening within a VBA script ?

Comment: @PavelMurnikov Nope. Access itself uses ODBC natively, afaik. While you _could_ go that way too, it's a ton of work and essentially reinventing the wheel. You can find the docs on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/developing-applications), and while it is feasible to map all C structs and functions to VBA ones, it's not exactly easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following will provide what you are looking for:

```
   Public Function DbEngineErrors() As String

  Dim intErr As Integer
  Dim strRet As String
  Dim strErr As String

  If DBEngine.Errors.Count > 0 Then
     strRet = "DbEngineErrors:"
     For intErr = 0 To DBEngine.Errors.Count - 1
        strErr = DBEngine.Errors(intErr).Number & " / " & DBEngine.Errors(intErr).Description & " / " & DBEngine.Errors(intErr).Source
        strRet = strRet & vbCrLf & strErr
     Next
  End If
  DbEngineErrors = strRet
  End Function
```

Comment: I already mentioned this method in my initial question

Comment: However, you did not mention checking the entire collection. Also, this method, typically does include the underlying error.

Comment: Of course I go through the entire DBEngine.Errors collection. Worth mentioning though that in my case this collection contains only one item anyway :)